# Android studio white screen on load up

Tags: android, webview, admob

Hello when i try to load my app(webview with a adview) up and i see a white screen and nothing happens this happen when i try to get adview to work

```
MainActivity.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="danilkp1234.com.pokemondamagecalculator.MainActivity">
<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 android:id="@+id/adView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 ads:adSize="BANNER"
 ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview">
    </WebView>
</LinearLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

pls help me with this if your need more info eks build.gradle

Comment: please, [consider looking how to load ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have written webview code at the bottom with height and width as match_parent, it will occupy whole screen. either use weight param inside LinearLayout with vertical orientation or use RelativeLayout with alignment rules.
Try this one, replace your code with below xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="danilkp1234.com.pokemondamagecalculator.MainActivity">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i get this error Error:(20, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:(20, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/adView').
C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout\activity_main.xml
C:\Users\danie\AndroidStudioProjects\PokemonDamageCalculator\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml